# Извлечение связанных данных в Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

Есть связи:

```
    public function getGroup()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Group::className(), ['id' => 'group_id']);
    }

    public function getKey()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Key::className(), ['key_board_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

Сформировал запрос (в модели Key_board):

```
    $data = $this::find()
    ->select(['id', 'name', 'group_id'])
    ->where(['scenario' => 1, 'user_id' => $user_id])
    ->with([
        'key' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(['id', 'value', 'key_board_id']);
        },
        'group' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(['id', 'foto']);
        }
    ])
    ->orderBy('order')
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Получаю данные вот в таком виде:

```
    [
        [ 
            'id' => '1', 
            'name' => 'ddd', 
            'group_id' => '2', 
            'key' => [ 
                [ 
                    'id' => '4', 
                    'value' => 'ggg', 
                    'key_board_id' => '1', 
                ], 
            ], 
            'group' => [ 
                'id' => '2', 
                'foto' => 'data',
            ], 
        ],
    ]
```

Неплохо, но хотелось бы получить примерно такой результат:

```
    [
        [ 
            'id' => '1', 
            'name' => 'ddd', 
            'group_id' => '2', 
            'key' => [ 
                [ 
                    'id' => '4', 
                    'value' => 'ggg', 
                    'key_board_id' => '1', 
                ], 
            ], 
            'foto' => 'data',
        ]
    [
```

Можно ли как-то изменив запрос, чтобы не корректировать данные вручную?

`key_board_id` и `group_id` тоже желательно убрать (из запроса нельзя - ошибка).

Спасибо.

---

*Пока сделал так:*

```
    foreach ($data as &$B) {
        if ($B['group']) {
            $B['foto'] = $B['group']['foto'];
        } else {
            $B['foto'] = '';
        }
        if ($B['key']) {
            foreach ($B['key'] as &$key) {
                unset($key['key_board_id']);
            }
        }
        unset($B['group']);
        unset($B['group_id']);
    }
```

Comment: Там же hasMAny(), поэтому не получиться убрать group. В этой ячейке может быть несколько моделей. Если убрать group_id и возникает ошибка, значит где есть обращение к этому полю.

Comment: Значит только вручную перестраивать структуру? Рассмотрю любые предложения.

Comment: Можно и вручную. Я бы получил сначала только модели, а потом их прогнал через foreach. В цикле можно какой хочешь массив сформировать.

Comment: Примерно так и сделал пока `добавил в пост временное решение`.